# Applying for a student visa in France. I have a question regarding a previous visa and stay in Germany

Tags: visa, germany, france, student-visa

I am a chemical engineer and I have plans for Master studies in France. I already have approval from the University and now it's time to apply for a student visa. I am from Tunisia by the way.

I traveled to the EU before for internships (Belgium for 3 months and Germany for a year). Near the end of my internship in Germany (end of 2015), my employer suggested a 3 months extension of my internship (possibility of employment by then and quite a load of work to handle by that time). The problem was that as a non-EU citizen I could not have an internship in Germany for more than a year. So I applied with a contract of ''vocational training'' along with the necessary documents (letter from the employer, forms...). I applied 2 weeks before the end of my visa and I had concerns that the application will take more time than that. Unfortunately, it did take a lot of time and I ended up waiting until the last day where I went there to check the situation.

Also, my application was denied. They said that the reason was that my income in the contract was not justified (even though that it's stated that I had a little more than the minimum wage). That day, I signed a document there saying that I understand the situation and that I had to leave Germany in 14 days max (they were very clear about that). I had that document with me at the airport and handed it to customs. I got a regular stamp on my passport and the agent wrote on top of it GÜS.

Does anyone know what this means exactly? Is it considered as a visa refusal (I am reading that you get a refusal stamp in this case?)?

Taking into account that I am applying for a student visa in France soon, can this affect my application? Should I state this as a visa refusal in the visa forms?

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: Corrected spelling + Please let me know if a detail in my description is not clear enough. Thank you for your time :)

EDIT 2: Hello @lafemmecosmique and @phoog, I was just re-checking the documents that I received back then and I thought to update the info that I had. So I have a document from the Bundesagentur fur Arbeit (Labor Agency) and 2 other documents from the officer at the foreigner office.

- The document from the labor agency states clearly that my qualifications do not match my remuneration (I applied with a vocational training contract).
- The interesting thing that I found out after translating the exact text from German in the document I signed in the foreigner office is the following:

"Date, address and name of the officer,
Mr XX speaks to the foreign authority in *city* on this day without being asked.
Mr XX is pointed out that the employment agency has rejected his application for further employment. Mr XX is pointed out that he has to leave the federal territory. Mr XX decides to cancel the application for the extension of the residence permit from 18.08.2015."

Do you guys have new explanations based on this new information? It says that I decided to cancel my application to extend my residence permit.

Thank a lot for your time! I really appreciate your help.

Comment: In general, you should be truthful; if they catch you in a lie you will be in a much worse position.  Given that the refusal was related to the specifics of your proposed income and not to your current personal circumstances, there's a good chance that effect of the previous refusal will be minimal.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I hope that this will have small or no effect on my application.

Comment: I don't think anyone can really answer this with certainty unless they actually work for the French visa office. That said, there is nothing on a French student visa application regarding previous visa denials, as far as I am aware. Also, your visa denial was based on income issues rather than deception or crime. Probably the French office will know from information sharing, and they will assess the rest of your app on its merits. Assuming you have a convention d'accueil or a convention de stage, I think you should probably be fine.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your response @la femme cosmique . I am already accepted in a Master program and I am financially ready. I hope this minor encounter won't affect my plans.